# Error in FTP connection using FTP Username, FTP Server?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have following details only

Host:ftp.xyz.com Port:21 User:xyz Password:xyz@123

When i am trying to connect ftp using Filezilla it show error like

Status: Resolving address of ftp.xyz.com

Status: Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known".

How can I resolve this error. Please help me for the same.

Thanks in Advance Guys!

Comment: You might have the wrong `Host` address.

Comment: The host address is all right.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: It is provide by cpanel.

Comment: Then you want to ask an `administrator`. Or you have a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address cannot be resolved. Try using the IP address instead, or delete ftp. from the beginning.

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya - So how did you solve it? This answer has more than one suggestion. :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Delete ftp. from the beginning . :-)